# Missing Public Assemblies folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Several articles and blogs I have read suggest placing assemblies I wish to make available to T4 in the Visual Studio *Public Assemblies* folder.  This is supposed to be located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`, but I have no `PublicAssemblies' folder there, only`PrivateAssemblies`.  Creating my own`PublicAssemblies` folder doesn't seem to work.  Assemblies located here are supposed to be available in the .NET section of the Add References dialogue, and my assembly located there is not.

**SOLVED:**
I was looking under Program Files, not Program Files (x86).  I found Public Assemblies in the latter location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about that folder, but MS suggests adding a registry key to make your assemblies available in VS as in this quote from this article: [How to display an assembly in the "Add Reference" dialog box](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306149)

*To display your assembly in the Add Reference dialog box, you can add a registry key, such as the following, which points to the location of the assembly*
`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\MyAssemblies]@="C:\\MyAssemblies"`
*where MyAssemblies is the name of the folder in which the assemblies reside.*

Comment: For those on 64-bit OS there is a more complete colution at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find the answer in another SO question: [Can't reference an assembly in a T4 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434713/cant-reference-an-assembly-in-a-t4-template/4656892#4656892)