# In T4 code generation, how can I grab a type from a referenced assembly?

Tags: c#, t4

Since T4 runs outside of the context of a project, I don't have access to the current assembly or other assemblies.  How can I register access to a referenced assembly, then grab a type from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you want to access an assembly your building in your project. What I've done in the sample code below is adding a project to my solution called TestLib which I build to the folder .\T4Libs in the solution directory. TestLib has a class called MyHelper which holds a magic number.

FYI VS2010 SP1 added the great feature in that it no longer locks the imported assemblies so that's a good version to use.

```
<#@ assembly   name        = "$(SolutionDir)\T4Libs\TestLib.dll"  #>
<#@ import     namespace   = "TestLib"                            #>

<#
   var myHelper = new MyHelper ();
#>

// <#=myHelper.MagicNumber#>
```

Comment: This works if you actually know the type - but what if you want to generate the type using a string?

Comment: As T4 is written in C# (or VB) you load assemblies using Assembly.Load and use Assembly.GetType to get the type.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [Assembly directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946.aspx) and/or are you looking for something in the [System.Reflection.Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) class (like LoadFile)?