# How do I see what dependency failed to load?

Tags: t4

[Can't reference an assembly in a T4 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434713/cant-reference-an-assembly-in-a-t4-template)

So when I put

`<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)"  #>` in the T4 template, it says

`The assembly $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName) could not be loaded. There was an exception during load: A dependency could not be found!`

As I understand it T4 has been updated to not lock assemblies so referencing the current project should be safe, but seems in a project with dependencies it gets to be horrendous to do.

how do I find out what the assembly that failed to load is?

Comment: Did your project build successfully before trying to transform the template?

Comment: yes it did. and there are many dependencies =/

Comment: Try fusion log Viewer to see how assemblies are loaded or fails to load: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Don't forget to turn off logging after you are done, it's a machine global setting.

Comment: You could try to temporarily change your template into a preprocessed template. If you then transform it at runtime it should fail, too. But maybe it's easier to detect the missing dependency there...

Comment: @FuleSnabel I see things going in to the fusion log, but hitting save on the template didn't change the log.

Comment: It's important to run fuslogvw.exe as administrator and you have to pick the 32bit variant if you run on 64bit machine (VS is 32bit). Once picked you have to enable logging on binding failures and I usually pick a custom path as well. If you select log all bindings you should see all bindings resolved during VS startup (quite a few). Once you triggered the error condition you click refresh. I tried this and it worked as I had it setup.

Comment: @FuleSnabel were you hitting refresh inside a T4 template to see bindings resolving? if so it has to be because I was running 64-bit fuslogvw

Comment: Yes I tried refresh after executing T4 template and that showed the bindings resolved by the template.

Comment: So I take the same assembly that is failing to load in `T4`, and load it in `LinqPad`, and it works just fine without referencing anything special... how annoying.